# Salesforce streaming API issue in version 37

Tags: java, streaming-api, cometd

I am using the salesforce java streaming API code that is provided in the [salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_java_client_intro.htm).

Code is working fine. But when I use the CometDReplyExtension for getting the events based on replayID, it not providing the result based on ReplayId.

Anyone have any idea on it?

For information: the code that is provided for extension was based on CometD java client version 3.0.10 so I changed according to CometD java client version 2.3.1. because the streaming code was based on 2.3.1 version

Comment: I updated the streaming code to be compatible with  the provided extension version but it is still not working.It is still showing the events with are currently being updated as client code is connected and not showing the past 24 hours events based on the replayid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After done all the changes in code side, the issue was with the datamap which was required for cometDReplayExtension. The correct key was channel name. I was using "ReplayId" as key. So now everything works fine. I am able to get the events based on replayId.